# Ubuntu fails to mount external RAID with "Disk read failed". How should I troubleshoot this?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

I'm trying to attach [a Mediasonic HFR2-SU3S2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003YFHEAC) to my ubuntu machine. It contains four WD Red 3TB NAS drives in RAID5. The following is the output of dmesg -w when I plug the drive into a usb port.

```
[ 2092.514195] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[ 2093.535785] ..ready
[ 2102.544008] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 2102.544278] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] 17581277184 512-byte logical blocks: (9.00 TB/8.19 TiB)
[ 2102.544283] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 2104.544317] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 2104.544323] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[ 2106.544409] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[ 2106.544418] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2141.611994] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 2296.095334] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2296.095341] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 2296.095345] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[ 2296.095351] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2296.095354] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 2296.095358] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2296.095366] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 2296.095368] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2297.119949] INFO: task fdisk:7277 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 2297.119957]       Tainted: P           OE     5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu
[ 2297.119960] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 2297.119964] fdisk           D    0  7277   7276 0x00000004
[ 2297.119969] Call Trace:
[ 2297.119981]  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
[ 2297.119988]  ? sr_do_ioctl+0x81/0x1b0
[ 2297.119992]  schedule+0x42/0xb0
[ 2297.119996]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
[ 2297.120000]  __mutex_lock.isra.0+0x182/0x4f0
[ 2297.120007]  ? exact_lock+0x11/0x20
[ 2297.120012]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[ 2297.120015]  mutex_lock+0x2e/0x40
[ 2297.120021]  __blkdev_get+0x78/0x550
[ 2297.120026]  blkdev_get+0x3d/0x140
[ 2297.120030]  ? blkdev_get_by_dev+0x50/0x50
[ 2297.120034]  blkdev_open+0x8f/0xa0
[ 2297.120041]  do_dentry_open+0x143/0x3a0
[ 2297.120044]  vfs_open+0x2d/0x30
[ 2297.120050]  do_last+0x194/0x900
[ 2297.120056]  path_openat+0x8d/0x290
[ 2297.120062]  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
[ 2297.120068]  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x150
[ 2297.120072]  do_sys_open+0x17e/0x290
[ 2297.120076]  __x64_sys_openat+0x20/0x30
[ 2297.120082]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[ 2297.120088]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[ 2297.120092] RIP: 0033:0x7f0e54476d1b
[ 2297.120101] Code: Bad RIP value.
[ 2297.120104] RSP: 002b:00007ffd0d7306c0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
[ 2297.120109] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd0d730740 RCX: 00007f0e54476d1b
[ 2297.120111] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000056064438d650 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
[ 2297.120113] RBP: 000056064438d650 R08: 00000000000001ff R09: 00007ffd0d7307d5
[ 2297.120115] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[ 2297.120117] R13: 00007ffd0d731820 R14: 00007ffd0d731820 R15: 0000560642d8df51
[ 2538.923913] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 2539.080496] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2539.080498] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2539.080500] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2539.080503] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2539.080509] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
```

I'm honestly not sure what I am reading here. This device worked fine on windows a few months ago (I no longer have a windows installation).  What should my next troubleshooting steps be? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How old is the drive? It may have been corrupted/failed completely. You might want to check its [S.M.A.R.T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) results.

Comment: @DeadVoid the enclosure and drives are about two years old and they see light use.  4 drives in RAID 5.  `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd` just hangs...

Comment: The "`Not ready`" and "`in the process of becoming ready`" should go away after a while, or it's dead

Comment: @waltinator  could you elaborate on "it's dead"?  I'm not sure how to figure out what exactly is dead.  All four drives?  Just some of the drives? The drives are fine but the enclosure is dead?  Something else is wrong?  How would I go about figuring this out? Thank you!

Comment: You will have to look into the  Mediasonic HFR2-SU3S2 box to see what have failed. Doesn't it have a management interface of some kind ? Apparently it only presents a LUN (/dev/sdd) to your host, not the single disks.

Comment: @SorenA The HFR2-SU3S2 has indicators that are supposed to show if a drive has failed.  It doesn't indicate any failures. Unfortunately there is no management interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the enclosure working this morning.  I simply pulled one of the drives out and put it back in.  The enclosure detected that a drive had been replaced and proceeded to rebuild.  This took several hours, and appears to have fixed the problem.
*I don't recommend anyone else do this unless they are prepared to lose data.*  I didn't lose anything, but if something had gone wrong I could have.